# Jsstore Add not being performed

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jsstore/dist/jsstore.min.js">      
</script>
<script 
 src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jsstore/dist/jsstore.worker.min.js"> 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" name="user" placeholder="user" id="user">
<input type="text" name="pass" placeholder="password" id="pass">
<input type="button" name="Submit" value="Submit" 
onclick="addStudent();">





<script type="text/javascript">
var connection = new JsStore.Instance();
window.onload = function () {

initiateDatabase();
getDb();

}

function initiateDatabase(){

var DbName="ProductDatabase"
function initJsStore() {
 connection.isDbExist(DbName).then(function(isExist) {
      if (isExist) { // checks if the database exists, if it does then opens it, else creates a whole new dataBase
          connection.openDb(DbName);
      } else {
          var database = getDbSchema1();
          connection.createDb(database);
      }
  }).catch(function(err) {
      console.error(err);
  })
  }
   }
   function getDb(){

    var productTable = {
     name: 'Product',
      columns: [
       {
          name: 'Id',
          primaryKey: true,
          autoIncrement: true
        },
        {
          name: 'Name',
          notNull: true,
          dataType: JsStore.DATA_TYPE.String
        },
       {
          name: 'Password',
          notNull: true,
          dataType: JsStore.DATA_TYPE.Number
       },

       ]
       }; 
  var db = {
      name: "ProductDatabase",
      tables: [productTable]
  }
  return db;
}

}




function addStudent() {
  var UserName = document.getElementById("user").Value;
  var Password= document.getElementById("pass").Value;
    var Value = {
        Name: UserName,
        Password: Password
    };

    connection.insert({
        into: 'Product',
        values: [Value]
    }).then(function (rowsAdded) {
      if(rowsAdded > 0){
          alert("Successfully Added");
      }

    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
        alert(err.message);
    })

}
</script>
```

What is wrong with my code ?
Is there something missing ?
I am trying indexed DB for first time and its with JsStore.

Explanation:

I am trying to add user name and password to the indexedDb and its unsuccessful attempt. Please point out my mistakes.I want it to be completely using javascript code no (JQuery).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`function initJsStore() {`

`var database = getDbSchema1();`

```
//removed above all
```

as they were sample code provided by the jsstore I had copied it but as of I don't need it

```
var UserName = document.getElementById("user").Value; // Value should be in lower case.
```

I had referred back to the example created by JsStore Developer.